# Forcing search engine to display stock quote in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, search

Is there a way (extension, tag) to input a stock ticker into the Google Chrome search bar and return the relevant yahoo finance/ google finance/bloomberg page for a stock?

Most of the time google is very good about showing a finance card but there are numerous tickers (KORS) comes to mind where the finance card doesn't show up at all.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is do a search with the ${Ticker} symbol which will bring up the Google card showing stock quotes.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

Include the word "Stock" after the ticker symbol, so the search engine has some context to search with.

Ie: `KORS stock`:

[image: Google Search result for KORS Stock]

Comment: Thats a great idea, unfortunately the extra 6 characters for adding a space and stock aren't exactly the time saving measure that i had hoped for.

Comment: If typing 6-7 more keystrokes are really eating up your time, then I'd suggest that using a browser to look up your stocks may not the best method you could be using. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome you can manage search engines used in the address bar and customize the keyword.

Settings -> manage search engines, or right-click the address bar and click Edit search engines.

Under "Other search engines" click Add

[image: Search Engine=Yahoo Finance. Keyword=$. URL with %s in place of query=https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s]

Now to search for a stock, type this in the address bar

```
$ kors
```

And it will automatically go to https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/kors

This works for any site where the ticker would be part of the URL.

For example, to use thestreet.com, use this search URL: https://www.thestreet.com/quote/%s.html